# Am I missing a rule when using e?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is for separation differentiation of the equation, with the original here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differential-equations-new/ab-7-6/e/separable-differential-equations-find-the-error

```
dy/dx = x(y+2)
```

I'm stuck on how a answer follows from a line to another after the integration part:

```
y=e^(x^2/2) . e^C1
```

```
y=Ce^(x^2/2)
```

How on earth does the C moved from being an exponential multiplier to a normal value? I must've missed an important rule in regards to e, but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be grateful

Comment: As written, this is wrong. So, check the source? Also, contextless questions aren't well received here, so I'd suggest adding some context as specified [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960)

Comment: $e^C$ is a constant and has been replaced with another constant, which they have also called C. Confusing, but not that uncommon. You often see "Where C is an arbitrary constant" at the end of each line.

Comment: In fact, $e^C$ is a constant, so it could be replaced by the constant $D$ to give $y=e^{x^2/2}D=De^{x^2/2}$. But since $D$ is a constant we may replace it by any letter we please $\alpha,W$ or even $C$ (as long as we explicitly say it is a constant).

Comment: If you're solving $y'=xy$ by separation of variables, you have $\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int x dx$ so $\ln(|y|)=x^2/2+C$ and then $|y|=e^{x^2/2+C}=e^C e^{x^2/2}$. In actuality what comes next is slightly more complicated than it looks at first. So first you strip out the absolute value, leaving you with $y=\pm e^C e^{x^2/2}$. Then you notice two things: first you've discarded the trivial solution $y=0$ when you did the separation of variables, and second the expression $\pm e^C$ in the "separable solution" can be any nonzero real number.

Comment: (Cont.) Thus actually $y=Ce^{x^2/2}$ is a solution for any real number $C$. Differential equations instruction often sweeps the details of this step under the rug a bit, by (incorrectly) writing $y=e^C e^{x^2/2}$ immediately and then "fixing their mistake with another mistake" by replacing $e^C$ with a general $C$ that is allowed to be nonpositive, even though $e^C$ is obviously positive.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of lumping constants. Say we have some constant $C$ and some other constants like $e, \pi$ or some physical constant and some function $f(x)$. In calculus we're typically less interested in the constants than the behavior of the function $f(x)$, the idea being that we can just look up the constant later if we actually need a number value.

This means that in an expression like $5\pi/e$ it can become cumbersome to rewrite the constant every time so instead we give it a name which is typically $C$. However later in the calculation you may come up with something like $C + 2\pi e^2$ or $C 2 \pi e^2$ which are also just constants. In these situations you now lump the constants together by creating some new constant $C_1 = C + 2\pi e^2$ or $C_1 = C2\pi e^2$. You then use this new constant $C_1$ in place of the old one from then on. However after a while this too becomes tedious and so often in rough work people just keep using $C$ instead of $C_1$ since the only important information is that it's a constant.